# Lighthouse Ci run on generated urls

Tags: javascript, lighthouse

Hi I want to run lighthouse ci on all pages in a static site generator. The below doesn't work. I need to wait for all of the page paths to be returned as an array (`urls`) and then passed in as the value to `url` in the lighthouserc config. When I run `lhci autorun` from the command line it's not picking up the `ci: {}` config.

```
const getPages = require('./lighthouse');

module.exports = (async () => {
  const urls = await getPages();
  const obj = {
    ci: {
      collect: {
        url: urls,
        numberOfRuns: 1,
      },
      preset: 'lighthouse:no-pwa',
      assertions: {
        'categories:accessibility': ['warn', { minScore: 0.9 }],
      },
      upload: {
        target: 'temporary-public-storage',
      },
    },
  };
  return obj;
})().catch(err => {
  console.error(err);
});
```